# Problemas con Estimote Beacons Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Si alguien a trabajado con Beacons Estimote, tal vez me pueda apoyar.
Necesito activar el servicio de Analytics, para lo que utilice el siguiente código en mi método onCreate:

```
EstimoteSDK.initialize(this, "Aquí va mi AppId", "Aquí va mi AppToken");
EstimoteSDK.enableMonitoringAnalytics(true);
```

Y la respuesta que recibo en el log es la siguiente:

```
E/EstimoteSDK: com.estimote.sdk.cloud.internal.analytics.AnalyticsManager$2.failure:260 Unable to obtain owned devices for Analytics
           com.estimote.sdk.exception.EstimoteServerException: 503 Service Unavailable
               at com.estimote.sdk.cloud.internal.InternalEstimoteCloud$7.failure(InternalEstimoteCloud.java:467)
               at com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.retrofit_v1_9_0.retrofit.CallbackRunnable$2.run(CallbackRunnable.java:53)
               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
            Caused by: com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.retrofit_v1_9_0.retrofit.RetrofitError: 503 Service Unavailable
               at com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.retrofit_v1_9_0.retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:387)
               at com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.retrofit_v1_9_0.retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$000(RestAdapter.java:219)
               at com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.retrofit_v1_9_0.retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$1.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:277)
               at com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.retrofit_v1_9_0.retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
               at com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.retrofit_v1_9_0.retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:134)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

De antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Ya diste un vistazo a su doc oficial? http://developer.estimote.com/android/tutorial/part-1-setting-up/

Comment: Si ya la eh revisado, con la documentación lo configuré y funciona correctamente, mi único problema es la función de analytics, pero no eh encontrado nada referente a este problema ni en sus foros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje de error define el problema:

> Caused by:
>   com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.retrofit_v1_9_0.retrofit.RetrofitError:
>   503 Service Unavailable

A rasgos generales el error indica que el servicio que intentas obtener no se encuentra disponible.

Pero en este caso trabajando con [Estimote](http://developer.estimote.com/), pueden ser otras 2 cosas:

- No estas correctamente autenticado y por esa razón no accedes a la url.
- Revisa que no tengas problemas al estar trabajando en un firewall y no te permita acceder a la url.

Comment: Efectivamente, fue un problema relacionado con la URL, y el problema lo tenía el proveedor del servicio, ya lo repararon, gracias!!!